# Why is DBHelper not closed in the Android notepad tutorial?

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

I am currently writing my first Android app and have based most of my knowledge on the Android notepad tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex3.html

In my application I am using multiple DBHelpers in one Activity and not every Cursor is managed by the activity with startManagingCursor().

I have learned that every DB connection has to be opened and closed propperly:

```
SQLiteOpenHelper.open();
Cursor.open();
//use cursor
Cursor.close();
SQLiteOpenHelper.close();
```

As far as I know startManagingCursor() does this work for you. But does startManagingCursor() also open and close the SQLiteOpenHelper?

The Android Notepad tutorial is using startManagingCursor() but the DBHelper is never closed. Why is the SQLiteOpenHelper never closed?

EDIT:

This is my current code. It is using one SQLiteOpenHelper called mDriverDbHelper. This code is an adoption from the tutorial:

private DriverDbAdapter mDriverDbHelper;

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bus_selectuser);
    mDbHelper = new DbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    mDbHelper.close();
    mDriverDbHelper = new DriverDbAdapter(this);
    Log.w("BuerBusActivity", "opening DB connection via DbHelber now");

    mDriverDbHelper.open();
    fillData();

    //request the screen to stay on
    this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}

@Override
public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();

    Log.v(TAG, "onRestart");
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mDriverDbHelper.open();
    Log.v(TAG, "onStart");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.v(TAG, "onResume");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    Log.v(TAG, "onPause");
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    mDriverDbHelper.close();
    Log.v(TAG, "onStop");
    super.onStop();
}
```

This code sample does work but I don't understand why. I am calling mDriverDBHelper.open() twice in onCreate and in onStart.

I have tried to put the open() and close() calls in onPause and onResume but this results in an error:

```
Cursor: invalid statement in fillWindow()
```

Does anybody know why it has to be onStart and onStop and not onPause and onResume?

**FINAL ANSWER**

The tutorial is missing a close() method call. A general rule to using open and close in conjunction with the activity life-cycle is:

*After opening an SQLiteOpenHelper in an activity life-cycle-method you should close it in the corresponding counterpart life-cycle-method.*

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    ....
    //open SQLiteOpenHelper
    onCreateHelper.open();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    ....
    //open SQLiteOpenHelper
    onStartHelper.open();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    ....
    //open SQLiteOpenHelper
    onResumeHelper.open();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    ....
    //close SQLiteOpenHelper
    onResumeHelper.close();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    ....
    //close SQLiteOpenHelper
    onStartHelper.close();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    ....
    //close SQLiteOpenHelper
    onCreateHelper.close();
}
```

In the case of the Android NotePad Tutorial the onDestroy() method was missing and should close the mDbHelper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per `startManagingCursor` documentation, it only handles cursors. So i believe it doesn't do anything with database connection as it may need to re-query data in future.

> *From Android Developer's site:*
>
> This method allows the activity to take care of managing the given
>   Cursor's lifecycle for you based on the activity's lifecycle. That is,
>   when the activity is stopped it will automatically call **deactivate()**
>   on the given Cursor, and when it is later restarted it will call
>   **requery()** for you. When the activity is destroyed, all managed Cursors
>   will be closed automatically.

Regarding database connection closing in android notepad tutorial, I think they have missed to close it in their sample code. So no big deal :)

Comment: Ok that was what I was thinking :-) Where would I close the SQLiteOpenHelper? Do I put it in the onStop() method? Do I also have to reopen it in onRestart()?

Comment: yes, open db connection in onStart or onResume and close it in onStop or onPause, respectively

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the sample code also doesn't deal with the real possibility of the user hitting the device's **back button**. This will likely cause null pointers to be passed via the bundle extras.  To keep the sample from crashing, you can just wrap a try / catch block around everything after the super call, like this:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        try {
              Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

              switch(requestCode) {
              case ACTIVITY_CREATE:
                     String title = extras.getString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE);  
                              // ^^^ LATER down goes KA-BOOM !
               // etc ... as in sample
              } // end switch stmt
         } catch (Exception e ) {
          Log.d ( "onActivityResult caught exception: ", e.toString() ) ;
         } // end try / catch
    // ...
```

Like C/C++ seems like *null* stuff is the most common error in Java ...

Answer (score 0):

Never close the DbHelper is designed to stay open forever.

And do not close the results of getReadableDatabase() and getWritableDatabase(), even is the same object in optimal conditions.

Check the source code, even the programmer don't like it:

```
private SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseLocked(boolean writable) {
    if (mDatabase != null) {
        if (!mDatabase.isOpen()) {
            // Darn!  The user closed the database by calling mDatabase.close().
            mDatabase = null;
        } else if (!writable || !mDatabase.isReadOnly()) {
            // The database is already open for business.
            return mDatabase;
        }
    }
...
}
```

And for stability and speed up use transactions, check this:
http://tech.vg.no/2011/04/04/speeding-up-sqlite-insert-operations/